# Firestore security rules missing permissions on create new document for new authenticated user

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to setup a role-based Firestore security rules but I'm stuck with how to create a new document if the incoming data uid matches with the auth uid.

But where to define that incoming uid?

I have tried to initialize the user uid of the new user to my model like this code below but it still missing some permissions.

```
final personalInfoData = PersonalInfoModel(
   uid: auth.getUid(),
   name: name,
   age: int.parse(age),
);
```

Here is my code looks like

```
match /profile/{profileId}/{document=**}{
    allow read: if isSignedIn() && docIdEqualsAuthId(profileId);
    allow create: if isSignedIn() && incomingUidEqualsAuthId();
} 

function isSignedIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
}
    
function docIdEqualsAuthId(profileId){
    return profileId == request.auth.uid;
}

function incomingUidEqualsAuthId(){
    return request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Here is my controller code :

```
String getUid() {
  return auth.currentUser!.uid;
}

final personalInfoData = PersonalInfoModel(
  name: name,
  age: int.parse(age),
);

DocumentReference profileCRef =
    firestore.collection("profile").doc(auth.getUid());

try {
  await profileCRef.set({'personalInfo': json}, SetOptions(merge: true));
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

The way I setup my controller is it will create a new document with a document Id of `request.auth.uid` of the new user.

I want rules to identify if the new user is authenticated and the incoming request to create a profile info must have a valid user id that matches with the auth uid.

If the document still not exists in the database then create a new document with an ID of the uid.

The error I'm getting is this

```
W/Firestore(14626): (24.0.1) [WriteStream]: (221034) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

W/Firestore(14626): (24.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at profile/N8CuobvPdHXr40KYgebw52SmOBp2: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

Comment: Can you try printing the UID that is being added in document right before `set()` and also the current user's UID and share the ouput ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj the output will be `N8CuobvPdHXr40KYgebw52SmOBp2` which is the auth uid of the current user logged in. I have updated my question with the error message I'm getting.

Comment: So the UID is inside of the personalInfo Map right? Try changing the rule to `return request.resource.data.personalInfo.uid == request.auth.uid;`

Comment: @Dharmaraj now it's working properly. So the it must refer to the type of data that we are sending right?

Comment: Your path to UID field was incorrect. UID is present in personalInfo and not directly in the doucment as a field (where current security rules are looking for.) I posted an answer for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.resource.data` is the data that you are trying to add in the document. Currently `uid` is not a field in document but a property in `personalInfo` map. So you must specify path to the field that you are trying to read in security rules. The following should work:

```
function incomingUidEqualsAuthId(){
    return request.resource.data.personalInfo.uid == request.auth.uid;
}
```